# Allow bit field to be set only if another bit field is set

Tags: sql-server, check-constraints

I have two `bit` fields in a table and on update I need to allow the second field to bet set (to `1`) only if the first field was already set.

So if a query updates the second field trying to set it to `1` the database must throw an error if the first field is not `1`, from the other side, if the query updates both of these fields at once setting them both to `1` - it must work.

Maybe this can be done with check constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a table level [CHECK CONSTRAINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx) should suffice.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable 
ADD CONSTRAINT CKC_BITS CHECK (FirstBit = 1 OR SecondBit = 0)
```